# Manage File permissions using REST API

Tags: permissions, file, rest

Is there a way to manage File permissions (roles) using the REST API?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx

I'm developing an app asking for permission on the fly:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470(v=office.15).aspx

I don't care about the way to do it... just want to upload a file to the SharePoint (already implemented that) - and then just make sure other users can't access it (before I delete it).

So any of these solutions will be just fine:

- set permissions on the file itself
- copy it to a folder and set permissions for that folder
- create a 'document library' and set permissions for it (this seems to be doable when you have FullAccess rights - which is not possible to get using the REST API)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to manage unique permissions for a Securable Object like [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list(v=office.15).aspx) or [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file(v=office.15).aspx) (via associated [List Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem(v=office.14).aspx)) or Folder (via associated [List Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem(v=office.14).aspx)) there is a common approach that you could consider:

- Break role inheritance for a securable object
- Add/remove the role assignment on the securable object *[optional]*

### How to: set unique permissions for a File via REST

**Step 1** Break role inheritance for a `List Item` associated with `File`

Example:

```
url: /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file relative url>')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)
method: POST      
Headers: 
   Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
   X-RequestDigest: form digest value
   accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
   content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

JavaScript example:

```
function breakRoleInheritanceOfFile(webUrl,fileUrl,success,failure) { 
     $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + String.format("/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)",fileUrl),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
            }
     });   
}
```

> Note: Specify `copyRoleAssignments=false` in `breakroleinheritance` method
>   to prevent copying the role assignments from the parent securable
>   object. In that case the collection of role assignments must contain only 1 role 
>   assignment containing the current user after the operation

**Step 2 (optional)** Add/remove the role assignment on the `List Item`

Remove the current role assignment for the group on the `File`:

```
url: /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file relative url>')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(<groupId>)
method: POST      
Headers: 
   Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
   X-RequestDigest: form digest value
   accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
   content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
   'X-HTTP-Method':'DELETE'
```

Add the new role assignment for the group on the `File`:

```
url: /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file relative url>')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=<groupId>,roledefid=<targetRoleDefinitionId>)
method: POST      
Headers: 
   Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
   X-RequestDigest: form digest value
   accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
   content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

### References

[How to: Set custom permissions on a list by using the REST interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495392(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: The only comment is that in order to use this API you need 'FullControl' permissions, so you need to use the Azure AD to get access tokens.

Comment: Thank you so much for "/ListItemAllFields" part of REST query, works great with getting folders by relative Url