# Break role inheritance and assign permissions to document with REST api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, office-365

I need to change the permissions of a document after the approval status has changed. I've to add the new user group to current document if the document has been approved.

I have used following links to achieve the goal:

- http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-(Item-Level-Permissions)
- http://www.sharepointbay.com/assign-permission-rest-api/
- http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2014/08/31/conditionally-set-permissions-on-new-documents-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx
- Is it possible or not ?

Comment: All the links you have shared suggest it is possible. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I'd follow the steps, but unable to do a single task of break role permissions for office 365.
Can you suggest for the same with Designer workflow 2013 and REST API approach ?

Comment: Breaking permission inheritance with the REST API as described in your first link works - I've just tried it for myself. So can't you just use the Call HTTP Web Service workflow activity with the appropriate REST URL endpoint?

Comment: Did you used in the Designer workflow 2013 for SharePoint online (Office-365) ?

Comment: No I used a Chrome browser plugin called Postman to send the request to SharePoint. Postman is useful to test REST API web service calls.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions with the above conditions to finish this task and is it feasible ?

Comment: Yes it is doable. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your comments you say you have made an attempt but can't break permissions inheritance in your workflow.

The answer to your question is yes, you can break permissions inheritance via the REST API from your SharePoint Designer workflow.

You will need to use the "Call HTTP Web Service" activity in your workflow and your URL will look like:

`https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file relative url>')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)`

If you need help using the Call HTTP Web Service workflow activity you can find various guides like [here](http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/10/09/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-working-with-web-services/), [here](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/), [here](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/04/using-the-call-http-web-service-rest-calls-in-sharepoint-online-using-spd/), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/05/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action.aspx).

Once you have broken permissions inheritance you can then assign your group to the document via the REST API using the `AddRoleAssignment` method. Again, you will need to use the "Call HTTP Web Service" workflow activity and your URL will look like:

`https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file relative url>')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=<groupId>,roledefid=<targetRoleDefinitionId>)`

The first link you posted has good information. You can also find an excellent answer with examples for a similar question on this site here:

[Manage File permissions using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113317/manage-file-permissions-using-rest-api)

Comment: Hello Submits,
Thanks for your valuable response for the post.

Comment: [This](http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html) one can explain in details.

Answer (score 3):

I'd finished this task with SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow without REST API.
[Click here for Link](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html)

final URL : [Click here for the full article which can explain in details](http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html)

Comment: Now also finished with the Designer Workflow 2013 and REST API with this [link] (http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2014/08/31/conditionally-set-permissions-on-new-documents-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx)

Comment: Also useful [link] (http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/)

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my opinion if you want to use SharePoint Designer, a good option would be to have a look at [Plumsail Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). This is a set of more that hundred workflow actions which could be very useful. 
As for your case you could use [Permission Management](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/Actions/Permissions%20management.html) section, it contains the whole specter of the actions for work with permissions.

P.S.: I'm working for Plumsail and I'm very happy to contribute to the product because I like it :)

Comment: Firstly Thanks, I got answer which is marked and very useful.
Plumsail Actions Pack is free or paid? Because it's an product so it could not be free as I think.
I am looking for the solution which is free of cost so that anyone can afford.

Comment: Yes, this is a paid solution, but I know how many time (and nerve cells:) ) it can save for anyone who designs workflows in SPD.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quite research finding below things regarding roleassignment. No specific post for these. It might help someone.

Adding to above all replies, I have not seen few things, like -

1. How to remove roleassignment
2. Restore the inheritance.

- Remove roleassignment :
  _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('')/ListItemAllFields/roleAssignments/removeroleassignment()
- Restore the inheritance :
  _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('')/ListItemAllFields/ResetRoleInheritance()

The same thing you can use it in Power Automate as well.