# REST API custom permissions peers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, rest

Can anyone confirm if you've encountered the following scenario?

I assigned a custom permission on a list item via REST API, using the workflow activity designer in VS 2013. I successfully broke and assigned custom permission supposedly for 1 user only, using the REST call.

```
https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=<userid>,roleDefId=<roledefid>)
```

But when I checked the list item it also lists the peers of that account. Is there a way to not include the peers when assigning the permission?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by Peers?

Comment: I think the peers are related to having the same Manager? I was checking the json and I saw that peers with the same manager are there as well.

Comment: I am not understanding how the Peers concept affects the permissions on a list item! Peers can belong to different groups and thus can have different permissions on the same list item! Please see my answer if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of setting unique permissions on a list item so that it is accessible to only one user, you need to first break the inheritance

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=**false**, clearSubscopes=**true**)
```

Now, you can add role assignment the way you did it.

Comment: I already broke inheritance then added the permission.

Comment: Ok and you made sure that you are not copying role assignments when you are breaking inheritance? I would help if you update the question to add this details also!

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api

Comment: Yes,I used <siteurl>_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Event Lines')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=true)

Comment: With regards to the peers concept, I'm actually granting permission to the manager of the user I'm adding. When I tried to grant permission to a user with no peers there were no additional users added to the item level permission.

Comment: Is it on My Site? It is confusing to me when you say ' I'm actually granting permission to the manager of the user I'm adding'. In your code, you are assigning permissions to only one principal. Is that the manager or the user? If it is manager, what do you mean by 'the user I am adding'?

Comment: In any case, it is worth removing the statement of add permissions and check if the breaking inheritance is working correctly before adding permissions.