# Break Role inheritance without Rest API with designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have one document library.
Once item /document is created / uploaded, one task will be assigned to a **Reviewer Group**, at that time need to change the permission of an item for the user who has created item, to **View only** and for the **Reviewer Group** to **Edit** that item.
If Reviewer has approved this task then again the permission of reviewer group will be view only and the **Approver** groups permission will be Edit.
So I have to do this with designer 2013 workflow and without Rest API.

Comment: looks like repeating questions http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api

Comment: I think that you have not read this question carefully.
Read it once!!

Comment: Now I have read the text "without Rest API".
But Ram you have not read your previous questions properly.
The first link you have mention in your previous question http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-(Item-Level-Permissions) 
in that article you can find line "There are no activities to break inheritance/assign permissions in SP2013 Workflows"

Comment: "There are no activities to break inheritance/assign permissions in SP2013 Workflows. It’s possible to invoke 2010 Workflow with this activities but it’s complicated and not possible in Apps. Thus the only way is REST API."
**That means have one option of Rest!!**

Comment: You can create Custom action.

Comment: What is the reason you can't use the REST API or use a SharePoint 2010 workflow?

Comment: I just want to know the another way to do the same task without Rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would Impersonation Step help?

The impersonation step runs as the last person who published the workflow and has the capability of removing permissions for an item/document:
[image]
*Screenshot source: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/04/15/impersonation-in-sharepoint-workflows-an-interesting-pitfall-aspx/*

1. Go to Site Settings>Site features> Enable 'Workflows can use app permissions'
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx
2. Add the impersonation step.
3. In the impersonation step, choose appropriate activity to remove/add permissions.

Here you have a sample user story:
http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/sharepoint-tips-app-step-or-impersonation-step-sharepoint-designer-2013

Comment: Is there **Impersonation Step** available with designer 2013?

Comment: There should be: Applies to
Microsoft SharePoint Online, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013, **Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013**, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2990213

Comment: If you are using 2013 workflow, the function has changed to "App Step", although Designer 2013 can still create 2010 workflow. App Step require to use whole bunch of REST API calls by HTTP actions.. Merit of using 2013 workflow over 2010 workflow? Future compatibility. I have no data whether 2013 style is better in performance.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Designer doesn't have an ability to manage permissions. To implement such user case I would offer you to use 3rd party tools.

Personally, I would recommend try [Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). It has [permission management workflow actions](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/Actions/Permissions%20management.html).

I'm one of the members of the dev team product and I'm proud of it.

Comment: Do you offer it free of cost?
I don't think that to purchase any third party tool!!

Comment: The price is $449 per year.

Comment: Ram the option suggested by Roman may be good. you can  use trial.

Comment: Is this available in the trial base #Roman?

Comment: Yes, the trial is available, please feel free to try it.