# Document permission on SharePoint library without REST API

Tags: document-library, permissions

I got a request where user wants: one super user to have full control to a document in library and all other site users should be able to view it.

However, once I break permissions to unique and add new users to site, will they be able to view this document?

Comment: you can use Declarative workflow for permission break inheritance. and after that you can add new permission to list item. like Super user full permission and renaming user read permission.

Comment: It would be depends upon the in which group you are adding the User.
So add in the proper group that's it.

Comment: What is your target? Would you like new users can view it or not? If you would like the new users can read it, add them to a group which has read permissions on this document. If you don't like that the new users can view this document, add them to a group which not has read permissions on this document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will they be able to view this document?**

This will depend on the permission level assigned to the new users , Once you have broken the inheritance for this document library , you can assign a unique permission for the new users to view it as the following :

If you have assigned

- `View Only` the users will be able to view pages, list items, and documents. Document types with server-side file handlers can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded.
- `Read` the users will be able to view pages and list items and download documents.

Comment: In this scenario, suppose there are users a,b who have access to site and library. I have broken inheritance and provided user 'a' full control to library. I want 'b' to have view access to documents in that library. And suppose I'm adding users c,d,e to site. I want them to have access to view documents without me going and adding them individually again to that library. Is that possible?

Comment: @FatimaFauzia Yes you can do this , instead of add user one by one , just create a group with your permission level "view only" and once you stop inheritance assigned this group for this library, now I will suppose you will add users c,d for the site , and rather than add these users one by one to doc lib , add them to this group , this will help you to organize and manage users permission easily

Answer (score 1):

You have an option of the break role inheritance,
With REST API-
[Click here for the reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api#answer-154638),

Without REST API-
[Break Role inheritance without Rest API with designer 2013 workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190944/break-role-inheritance-without-rest-api-with-designer-2013-workflow)

Just go through the link and you can find the answer.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use REST API's :(

Comment: Good, then please mention it while you asking questions next time.

Comment: Check the answer once, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

As per My Understanding, You want to know if the you have unique permission on the Document Library( broken inheritance). In that case if you add a new user at Site collection, will it able to view the Documents.

Short Answer is **No**, as you have unique permission on that library, unless you add the new user in that library manually.

But if you want to give the Read Permission to the new User to that library then

- Create a Group, Add all User( who want to view)
- Break Inheritance, remove everybody > Add that group with read Permission and Single User as Super User.
- Now when you wana add more people to the site, simply add them in that group. they will automatically get the view permission on the library.

Comment: Great, If that helps you, please dont forget to mark it answer with Vote up...thats what we need all the time

Answer (score 0):

Give all users Read permission and one super user Full control permission on the document library after breaking inheritance

Answer (score 0):

First you have broken the inheritance for this document library items , then you can assign a unique permission for the new users to view

Here are some Article

[Conditionally Set Permissions on New Documents in SharePoint 2013 Workflow](http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2014/08/31/conditionally-set-permissions-on-new-documents-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx)

[SharePoint 2013 REST API – How to set Unique Permissions (Item Level Permissions)](http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-(Item-Level-Permissions))

[How to Create a Workflow to Change Item Level Permissions](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html)

Comment: Cannot use workflows. Client doesn't support. Also I'm an admin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a password for the document that only the super user has, upload the document and users will be able to open it but will not be able to make any changes.

For advanced protection you should like said earlier break the inheritance and give specific users read only while the super user has design (example).