# Can I have restricted permissions on a document library view?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a document library by which I want staff to only see items they create or modify.  However, I want supervisors to see all items.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, This is possible.
The option is Brake role inheritance of the document library.
Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a page.
- Add your doc library as a web part.
- Then modify the web part's view.
- This will be exclusive to this page. Then set permissions on the page.

That satisfies the question in the title.

- You can use a workflow to trim item level permissions and can set to a sharepoint group of supervisors, Created By, and Modified By.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps as in the given URL-
Please [click here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api#answer-154638).

You can do that with the SP 2010 and 2013 designer workflow.

Once you set the access to the list/Library/ items then they are only accessible to the mentioned group/s or people/s that is view of the list or library.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the option to "only see items they create or modify", then you can't allow supervisors to see those items.

You'll need a workaround to make this work, for example use folders with custom permissions (one per contributor), or individual file permissions, or workflows (to modify permissions, or move files to a library where supervisors have access).

Answer (score 0):

Create a default view that only show the documents created or modified by [me]. That way user will only see the documents created or modified by them. Then remove the Allitems.aspx view from library setting. However, when you type out the URL of the view, you can still see and supervise all the documents.