# Unable to remove all the roleAssignments from List Item using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow

I am trying to delete all the role Assignments of a list Item using `REST API` in `SharePoint 2013 workflow`. The REST query returns the response code as OK but the role Assignments are not removed.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
REST query : 

[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/getbytitle('[%Workflow Context:List Name%]')/items([%Current Item:ID%])/roleassignments
```

Below is the screenshot

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to break role inheritance of the list item here -

try below url:

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/getbytitle('[%Workflow Context:List Name%]')/items([%Current Item:ID%])/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

Comment: No Luck .It did not work

Answer (score 1):

Please check the reference [URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api#answer-154638).

you can get in details and step by step solution to remove and assign the roles i.e Brake Role Inheritance with Rest API.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all role assignments you need to break inheritance with options. Your rest call to remove all roles should be similar to this:

```
url: siteUrl + String.format("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + confidencialDocumentId + )/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)"),
```

note the `copyRoleAssignments=false`