# Sharepoint Calendar shared on outlook

Tags: calendar

I want to make SharePoint calendar read only and some users can edit it.
Is there a way of doing so?

Answer (score 2):

The calendar is a list itself, and you can edit permission on the calendar, if you want them differently than the site where the calendar lives.

1. Browse to you calendar, and switch to the view "All Events"
2. On the list tab, select "Shared With"-button to the right
3. On the dialog-window, hit the Advanced link
   [image]
4. Here you can "Stop inherit permissions" and give selected users permission needed to add events (Edit permission).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Break Role Inheritance.

For more [click here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api#answer-154638) to get in details.

Hope this will help you!