# Set Folder Unique Permission using Designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I am creating a folders in document library(Static folder/subfolder1). For this subfolder1 i want to break the inheritance permission and set unique permission. And permission should be assigned to only creator and manager. These values we will capture it from the list form where this workflow runs.

If you have any inputs or suggesstion please send it in detailed screen shot.

Note: We have to use SharePoint 2013 workflow to create dynamic folder and set unique permission for those folder. Workflow will run from custom list.

Answer (score 0):

To break inheritance and set unique permissions you will need to use the `Call HTTP Web Service action` specifying the `breakroleinheritance` and `roleassignments/addroleassignment` methods, as there isn't any workflow actions that perform this out of box.

The following post describes in detail

[Break role inheritance and assign permissions to document with REST api?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154232/break-role-inheritance-and-assign-permissions-to-document-with-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Creating folders and sub-folders using SharePoint 2010 designer workflow:

http://365hq.net/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/

How to create a workflow to change item level permissions:

http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html