# Break inheritance on a folder using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint Online farm. I am trying to break inheritance on a folder in a document library, and then assign permissions to user(s), all via the REST API.

I can run this command successfully (a folder object is returned):

```
https://mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/DocLib/folder1')/
```

But when I try to run this command I get a 403 Forbidden error:

```
https://mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/DocLib/folder1')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/113322/47068 you need change

```
https://mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/DocLib/folder1')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

to

```
https://mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/DocLib/folder1')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

Comment: This still generates a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: I was getting the 403 because I was using https on my REST call. I switched to http and it all worked fine.