# break folder inheritance REST

Tags: permissions, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, inheritance, break-inheritance

I am trying to break inheritance using Rest. But I am getting error **Undefined**.

I am using below code :

`var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
     var headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
     var endPointUrl = url + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Style%20Library')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)"
    $.ajax({ 
            url: endPointUrl,
            type: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data)
            {
               console.log('Inheritance Broken Successfully!');
            }
           error: function (error)
           {
             console.log(error.message);
           }`

Any leads, where it is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the permissions on Style Library to break inheritance or to change the permissions??

Comment: Yes. I am the site admin.

Comment: I guess in SharePoint, by default inheritance is broken on Style Library, Can you please check again if you have permissions on style library from settings->Permissions for this document library->Check Permissions

Comment: Inheritance is not broken on style library. I am the admin of site and I have permission on style library too.

Comment: Are you able to access `https://yoursite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Style Library` from you browser? Try this directly in your browser window.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access the url from the browser directly. Although it is not working in browser if I use`('/style library')` as you suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95861/discussion-between-notorious-and-ganesh-sanap).

Answer (score 1):

Try using your endpoint URL like given below:

```
var endPointUrl = url + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Style%20Library')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)"
```

**Similar questions for Reference**:

1. [Break inheritance on a folder using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210875/break-inheritance-on-a-folder-using-rest).
2. [Sharepoint Rest API breakRoleInheritance Of Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520922/sharepoint-rest-api-breakroleinheritance-of-folder).

Comment: NO change. Same error.