# How to: set unique permissions for a sub-folder of a Document Set via REST

Tags: 2013, document-library, subfolders, unique-permissions

I am trying to achieve something similar to this: [Break inheritance on a folder using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210875/break-inheritance-on-a-folder-using-rese) below but at a level that is one deeper.

I can successfully break inheritance on a Document Set each time a new one gets added to my document library using the following REST call, as per the above answer:

```
https://sites/mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/DocLib/DocumentSetName')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true)
```

I can then apply successfully any new permissions that are necessary by making calls in the following format, all well and good:

```
https://sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/DocLib/DocumentSetName')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/AddRoleAssignment(principalid='XXX',roledefid='1073741826')
```

However there is also a sub folder that gets created underneath the document set that I need to modify the permissions on as follows (this doesn't work but highlights what I am trying to achieve):

```
https://sites/mysite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/DocLib/DocumentSetName/My Sub Folder')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true)

https://sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/DocLib/DocumentSetName/My Sub Folder')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/AddRoleAssignment(principalid='XXX',roledefid='1073741826')
```

I can break inheritance and change the unique permissions on the /DocLib/DocumentSetName/My Sub Folder through the UI so I am fairly sure I should be able to do this via REST but am not able to figure out the correct call to make.  Searching about hasn't revealed much on this.

UPDATE: If I just have a folder structure in the document library such as DocLib/Folder/My Sub Folder I am able to change the permissions on the /My Sub Folder as expected by using the calls above.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using jQuery ajax or Javascript fetch method? It does not seem you have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You have to use the POST METHOD in both cases:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/Testing2/SubFolder1')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false)

/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/Testing2/SubFolder1')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/AddRoleAssignment(principalid='XXX',roledefid='1073741826')
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I was using the POST method to make these calls

Comment: Use the rest api end points above and it should work.
Provide the correct user/group Id in the principal property

Answer (score 0):

After some further testing, it turns out that I wasn't looking in the correct place when looking at the permissions for the sub folder.  Quack quack.

I was trying to see who was assigned by using the Permissions button in the ribbon for the given document set sub folder:

[image]

When in actual fact I needed to use the Shared With item in the drop down for the sub folder:

[image]

It was working as expected all along.