# SharePoint clear roles to a folder error

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, folder

I try to clear assignment to a SharePoint folder. When I test it is not showing any error but appears this:

> "BreakRoleInheritance": null

And the folder maintain the same permissions.

The definition of the http is:

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(214)/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)
```

Where 214 is the ID of the folder.

Do you know where is the mistake?

Comment: Do you have Edit/Full control permissions on document library/folder?

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

To break permissions inheritance on folder inside document library, you have to use the REST endpoint like:

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents/folder1')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

**References**:

1. [Manage File permissions using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113317/manage-file-permissions-using-rest-api/113322#113322)
2. [Break inheritance on a folder using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210875/break-inheritance-on-a-folder-using-rest)
3. [Sharepoint Rest API breakRoleInheritance Of Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520922/sharepoint-rest-api-breakroleinheritance-of-folder)