# Is there a way to grant permissions to a sharepoint folder via REST APIs?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, folder, roles, sharepoint-permissions

Currently I created a folder in sharepoint and break its inheritance from the parent library through a REST endpoint. Then I created permission groups and assign permission roles to them. But now I need to assign this permission groups to newly recent folder. I wonder if there is a way to accomplish that via some sharepoint REST API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manage File permissions using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113317/manage-file-permissions-using-rest-api)

Comment: It does not. I did try this one before

Comment: In that suggestion there is a link to the [REST api documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-custom-permissions-on-a-list-by-using-the-rest-interface) - maybe that can be of help? If not, you could try providing a sample of the code you are writing.